# PostSharp in a multitenant solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postsharp

I'm currently looking to add PostSharp logging (and possibly other custom aspects) to an ASP.NET Core API project. The problem I'm running into is that we have a multitenant design where the tenant info is stored in the user claims, and there doesn't seem to be a good way to get at the current session from a PostSharp aspect, so there doesn't seem to be a good way to access the proper tenant's database.

Am I just barking up the wrong tree? Is there a different AOP framework I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness' sake, here's the solution I came up with, which uses both PostSharp and AutoFac.

PostSharp aspects can create properties on classes that they're applied to at compile time. Using AutoFac's `InjectUnsetProperties` function, we can inject properly-scoped members into these classes *even if we don't know about them at compile time*.

So, we set up our PostSharp aspect:

```
    [PSerializable]
    public class LoggingAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
    {
        [IntroduceMember(Visibility = Visibility.Public, OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.Ignore)]
        [CopyCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportMemberAttribute))]
        public IInjectedObject InjectedObject { get; set; }

        [ImportMember("InjectedObject", IsRequired = true)]
        public Property<IInjectedObject> InjectedObjectProperty;

        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            var data = InjectedObjectProperty.Get().MyData;

            Debug.Print($"OnEntry: {args.Method.Name}, Data: {data}\n");
        }

        public object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
        {
            return MemberwiseClone();
        }

        public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
        {
        }
    }
```

then register the service that we want to use the aspect on in our `Startup` method:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);

    builder.RegisterType<TestService>().As<ITestService>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
        .OnActivated(e => e.Context.InjectUnsetProperties(e.Instance))
        ;
    builder.RegisterType<InjectedObject>().As<IInjectedObject>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
        ;

    var container = builder.Build();

    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

and add the aspect to the method we want to log:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public TestService()
    {
        Debug.Print("TestService ctor\n");
    }

    private int _myData = 100;

    [LoggingAspect]
    public int GetData()
    {
        return _myData++;
    }
}
```

When the service is created during a request, a new one is created scoped to that request, and it gets a new `IInjectedObject` stuck into it which is also scoped to the request, even though the IInjectedObject property doesn't appear in our source code.